Corporate finance for mathematicians
Most corporate finance textbooks tend to be quite a bit verbose, like Brealey/Myers/Allen is around 900 pages. Quite a bit of the book teaches you how to calculate percentages (discounting). The substance to page ratio unfortunately tends to be very low in these types of books. I am looking for resources that introduce corporate finance in a mathematical way but with brevity.

There is very little math in corporate finance.

@AKdemy however there is some corporate finance in the mathematical theories that deal with, say, the Merton firm value model or with funding value adjustment. Personally I had the same problems of boredom as OP and wished many times there was such a terse book.

@Who cares:  This book ( see title in next comment ) might be more what you and Kurt are looking for. The title could be misleading because it could be titled "asset pricing".  John Cochrane also has a well known book ( titled asset pricing ) that you should take a look at also. They are all probably expensive so I don't want to say "GET THEM ALL".

@AKdemy not true at all that there is little math in corporate finance. Look at Gilles Chemla and Christopher Hennessy, both are theorists in corporate finance and do so much math.

"Lectures on Corporate Finance" by Peter Bossaerts and Bernt Arne Odeergard. It's much different from Brearley and Myers.  At the same time, it probably doesn't meet your brevity requirement and neither does Cochrane !!!!! –

@markleeds Thanks! "Lectures on Corporate Finance" seems like a delightful upgrade over BMA

I should have said applied corporate finance. From a practitioners point of view, I have not yet come across any actual asset liability management, budgeting or financing decision that required more than simple math. That's completely different for derivatives trading for example.

Who cares: I hope it helps you.  Peter Bossaerts is a very good writer IMHO. If you end up liking, "Lectures on Corporate Finance", he also has a second book, "The Paradox of Asset Pricing". It's best to check this one out after the Lectures one because it's written in a style that assumes that you know whats in Lectures. I originally tried to read it first and I don't recommend doing that.
